# using KnockoutJS with JQuery with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, drag-and-drop

I want the `$root.addField` action to happen whenever I drag my items onto the `DROP THINGS HERE` div. Just like what happens when you click the `add field` button.

Here is a fiddle so you can play with it -- http://jsfiddle.net/pt6k26kh/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var initialData = [
    { formTitle: "formTitle", formDescription: "formDesc", fields: [
        { fieldId: "text1", title: "title", description: "description Field", isReq: true },
        { fieldId: "text2", title: "ttitle22", description: "description Field 2", isReq: false }]
    },
      { formTitle: "formTitle", formDescription: "formDesc", fields: [
        { fieldId: "text1", title: "title", description: "description Field", isReq: true },
        { fieldId: "text2", title: "ttitle22", description: "description Field 2", isReq: false }]
    }

];

var FieldsModel = function(fieldTemplates) {
    var self = this;
    self.fieldTemplates = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(fieldTemplates, function(fieldTemplate) {
        return { 
            formTitle: fieldTemplate.formTitle, formDescription: fieldTemplate.formDescription, 
            fields: ko.observableArray(fieldTemplate.fields) };

    }));

    self.addfieldTemplate = function() {
        self.fieldTemplates.push({
            formTitle: "",
            formDescription: "",
            fields: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };

    self.removefieldTemplate = function(fieldTemplate) {
        self.fieldTemplates.remove(fieldTemplate);
    };

    self.addField = function(fieldTemplate, e) {
        console.log("---addField");
        console.log(e);

        fieldTemplate.fields.push({
            fieldId: "text",
            title: "",
            description: "",
            isReq: false
        });

    };

    self.removeField = function(field) {
        $.each(self.fieldTemplates(), function() { this.fields.remove(field) })
    };

    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.fieldTemplates), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new FieldsModel(initialData));

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <h2>Forms</h2>
    <div id='contactsList'>
        <table class='contactsEditor'>
            <tr>
                <th>Form Title</th>
                <th>Form Description</th>
                <th>Fields</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: fieldTemplates">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind='value: formTitle' />
                        <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removefieldTemplate'>Delete</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input data-bind='value: formDescription' /></td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: fields">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input data-bind='value: title' /></td>
                                    <td><input data-bind='value: description' /></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: isReq' /></td>
                                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeField'>Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addField'>Add field</a>     

                        <div class="dropped" data-bind='event: {drop: $root.addField}'>DROP THINGS HERE</div>                  
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="droppings" >
        <div data-bind='drag: {value: $data}' class="toDrop">toDrop 1</div>
        <div data-bind='drag: {value: $data}' class="toDrop">toDrop 2</div>
        <div data-bind='drag: {value: $data}' class="toDrop">toDrop 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropped" data-bind='event: {drop: $root.addField}'>DROP THINGS HERE</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(".droppings .toDrop").draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            drop: function(event, ui){
            }
        }); 

        $(".dropped").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui){
                $(".dropped").append('<div class="beenDropped">beenDropped</div>');
                console.log("dropped");
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: add field button click works as expected because it is inside the scope of <tbody data-bind="foreach: fields">. The $data in <div data-bind='drag: {value: $data}' class="toDrop">toDrop 1</div> is the actual FieldsModel and not the fields array as this is outside the table

Comment: So is this not technically possible? can it be made to work? I'm working custom forms using this design.

Comment: I'm still not very clear on the actual layout/user experience of the page. What is the purpose of giving a drag and drop option? What does toDrop1,toDrop2 etc signify. How is it different from the Add field button?

Comment: The addField button is NOT in the <tbody>. This is a simple version of the type of thing we are trying to do. Drag & Drop is a better user experience for our design than a click.

Comment: So when you drag and drop toDrop1, where do you expect the addField action to happen? on the last formTemplate.Fields collection?

Comment: I expect the same thing to happen to happen as if i were clicking the 'add field' button. I want an item to be pushed into the array of fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66703/discussion-between-sherin-mathew-and-maylortaylor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion above and my understanding of the problem I think we should do the following.

Add a new method called

```
self.globalAddField = function(){
   self.addField(self.fieldTemplates()[self.fieldTemplates().length-1])
}
```

The new method will pass the last item of the self.fieldTemplates() as an argument to the existing addField method. The rest of the functionality will remain same.

Modify the HTML as below.

```
<div class="dropped" data-bind='event: {drop: $root.globalAddField}'>DROP THINGS HERE</div>
```

Updated fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/pt6k26kh/2/